# O(N) lookups but O(log(N)) comparisons when using upper_bound on a sorted list

Tags: c++, list

```
list<Person> lp;
...
lp.sort(PersonNameLess());

Person newPerson;
...
lp.insert(upper_bound(lp.begin(), lp.end(), 
          newPerson, PersonNameLess()), newPerson);
```

In the effective c++ 3rd edition, page 198, Item 45, it says as follows:

> the lookup takes linear time, but it performs only a logarithmic
>   number of comparison

Question: *Why does it perform only a logarithmic number of comparisons?*

Comment: Wow... I had no idea `binary_search` and friends only required forward iterators...

Answer (score 4):

> Why does it perform only a logarithmic number of comparisons?

Because the list is sorted and [upper_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) perform a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: And moving the iterator to the next comparison site takes linear time because it's a list.